# Selenium and Cucumber in a Java/SpringBoot enironment - automatic retry of failed tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I've got a rather large test suite with Selenium/Cucumber, which runs in a Java/Spring-Boot/Angular environment.

The problem is the classical one: Flaky tests, due to page hickups and/or server/environment issues.

I know there is a way to set cucumber to retry failed tests a number of times. I've seen some rather advanced solutions, with the creatin of a failed tests list, then rerunning these afterwards, etc.

But the I came across this, which is said to be available in newer Cucumber versions:

```
cucumber --retry 2
```

The questions is: How to implement this in my setup?

Here's my CucumberTest.java file, where plugins, location of features etc. are specified:

```
Slf4j
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin   = { "pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json", "html:target/cucumber-html-report",  },
    tags = { "~@integration", "~@Ignore", "~@ToggledOff", "~@Known_error" },
    features = { "src/test/resources/features" })

public class CucumberTest {

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    log.info("\n\n-------------------------------------------------------\n" +
        " RUN ALL SCENARIOS FOR System\n" +
        "\n-------------------------------------------------------\n"
    );

}

@AfterClass
public static void quitTestSuite() {
    Hooks.closeConnections();
    Hooks.stopWatchTotalTime.stop();
    StringBuilder slowTests = findPotensialSlowTests();
    log.info("\n\n-------------------------------------------------------" +
            "\nALL SCENARIOS FINISHED FOR SYSTEM" +
            "\nTotal time         : {}" +
            "\nNumber of scenarios: {}" +
            slowTests.toString() +
            "\n-------------------------------------------------------\n"
        , Hooks.stopWatchTotalTime, Hooks.scenarioCounter.get());

}
```

Any ideas? Is there a place for that (and potentially other) cucumber option in this file? Or somewhere else? All help/hints are appreciated.

UPDATE: Silly question, but is "cucumber-jvm" named "cucumber-java" in the config files and other places? I cannot find the line cucumber-jvm anywhere, but I do find cucumber-java.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `retry = 2` line after the below line in your `CucumberTest.java` file inside the `@CucumberOptions` annotation

```
features = { "src/test/resources/features" },
```

Comment: Could you show me where in the code the retry option sits? https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/cucumber-junit/src/main/java/io/cucumber/junit/CucumberOptions.java

Comment: You can see it here https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/retry.md

Comment: That's for Cucumber in Java Script. OP is using Java

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber-JVM doesn't support retry.

However if you use Cucumber [in combination with Maven](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html) you can use:

```
mvn -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=2 test
```

Do note that this will effectively run Cucumber twice. So any reports generated by Cucumber will be overwritten by the rerun.

Also note that the reports generated by Maven aren't great. They get better if you use Cucumber in combination with the [Cucumber JUnit Platform Engine](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine) (JUnit 5).

Comment: Does it re-run the whole suite if one test fails, or just the one failing? Also, I'm getting unresolvable errors with the SureFire plugin, so that will probably never work in my setup :-/

Comment: Also, I'm getting a bit confused, as per the update in the question. Is cucumber-jvm the same as cucumber-java?

Comment: Surefire will rerun only the failing tests. Though it may rerun the entire suit if you're on an old version of Cucumber JVM.

Comment: Cucumber Java is part of Cucumber JVM. Just as Cucumber JUnit is part of Cucumber JVM. Did you look at the project? https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm